# prevent custom widget file names from showing in Appearance > Editor

Tags: widgets, editor

I've setup a few custom widgets for my theme, and when I go into Appearance > Editor, the widget file names are showing up in the list of files that can be edited.

How can I prevent these widget file names from showing up in the Editor's list of files? I put them in a subdirectory ("widgets"), but they are still showing up on the list with the main pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editor won't traverse more than one directory deep, so a simple way to hide them is to put them in a dir within a dir:

```
/inc/widgets/my-widget-file.php
```